# differences between phrases

Tags: meaning, phrases

As native speakers, do you find any difference between the following:

> 1. came into my mind
> 2. occurred to me
> 3. crossed my mind

They all sound the same to me. Does the same apply to you?

Answer (score 2):

All of these are essentially synonymous with "to think (of)".  However, the first should be "came *to* mind" and not "came into my mind".

> I know you can't remember the name of the store, but please text me if if **comes to mind** (= "if you think of it").

"Come to mind" in this context means "remember", but in other contexts it can mean to *actively* think of something, although usually without knowing what the result will be:

> Tell me the first color that **comes to (your) mind**

Both "cross my mind" and "occur to me" mean that you weren't *actively* trying to think of something, but you just happened to think of it.

> It **crossed my mind / occurred to me** the other day that it's been 25 years since our trip to Europe.

Other expressions:  *happen to think of*, *dawn on me*, *get (something) into my head*, *spring to mind*, and probably many other colloquialisms

Comment: Hmm.... but "come into my mind" googles almost 1m results and this: **occur to sb** — if an idea or a thought occurs to you, _it comes into your mind_ (Longman Phrasal Verbs, 2nd Ed.)  VERB + MIND ▪ **come into, come to**, cross, enter, flash across, **flash into**, go through, spring to (Oxford Collocations Dictionary 2nd Ed.)

Comment: @MvLog  There's nothing wrong with "come into my mind" in the right context, for example, ["What should I do if thoughts **come into my mind** while meditating?"](https://www.reddit.com/r/Meditation/comments/4xhtps/what_should_i_do_when_thoughts_come_into_my_mind/)  This is the definitive "come into" meaning "enter", not an idiom.